# Make GitHub Desktop work from WSL on Linux repositories

Tags: github, windows-subsystem-for-linux, github-desktop

I am using Windows to do some Linux development with WSL.

When I add Linux repositories to GitHub, it recognizes them, but it gets confused with file names and line endings between Linux and Windows.

This doesn't happen on the terminal tools inside `git > Ubuntu > WSL`, but it does happen on `git > Windows`.

Is there a way to either run GitHub Desktop's GUI on Ubuntu within WSL or to make the Windows version run its internal git commands through WSL's `bash`? Maybe a git configuration in Windows to make it Linux-aware?

Answer (score 0):

I use this repo https://github.com/andy-5/wslgit
With this, you can use the linux git from windows.

To make it work with Github Desktop you have to replace the git it uses, it is in the folder C:\ProgramData\User\GitHubDesktop\app-2.9.12\resources\app\git\cmd

Be careful because it changes every time Github Desktop is updated and you have to change it again.

The git used by Github Desktop is different from the linux one and sometimes some errors come out, I have had to install the git-lfs and git-core packages.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this https://github.com/shiftkey/desktop? I wasn't able to sign in though but it worked for me for existing repos in the file system